# What does the phrase "year-round" modify?

Tags: grammar

> Situated at an elevation of 1,350m, the city of Kathmandu, which looks out on the sparkling 
>   Himalayas, enjoys a warm climate **year-round** that makes living there pleasant.

What does *year-round* modify?  Does it modify the verb *enjoy* or the phrase *a warm climate*?  Could you help me clarify it?  Thank you always.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the word [**year-round**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/year-round) is an adverb (it can also be used as an adjective, by the way) which modifies the verb *enjoys*. It tells you how the city of Kathmandu enjoys its warm climate—it does that all year long. Meaning, the place has warm weather conditions throughout the entire year which is what, according to the person who wrote this passage, makes living there such a pleasant experience.

You should remember that in English adverbs can only modify verbs (*she talks loudly*), adjectives (*he is very tall.*) and other adverbs (*the show ended too quickly*). They never modify nouns, compound nouns or noun phases. So, locutions such as *beautifully girl* or *largely house* don't really make a whole lot of sense. In your case, *a warm climate* is a compound noun. Therefore, the adverb *year-round* can't possibly modify it. The verb *enjoy* is the only thing there that it can go with.

Answer (score 1):

**Year-round** in this sentence is used as an adverb to describe **how** the warm climate is enjoyed.  It works to modify or add information to the verb **enjoy** (says how it's enjoyed).

often the phrase year-round acts as an adjective and usually precedes  the noun it modifies.

e.g. A year-round resort.

e.g. Cricket is a year-round spot in India.

Answer (score -1):

It means that the city enjoys a warm climate that lasts the whole year.